# Msgbox Invalid Outside Procedure

Tags: vba

I have a problem in VBA(so I'm new).

I have a error with this code

```
Dim Msg, Style, Title, Help, Ctxt, Response, MyString
Msg = "Do you want to continue ?"    ' Define message.
Style = vbYesNo + vbCritical + vbDefaultButton2    ' Define buttons.
Title = "MsgBox Demonstration"    ' Define title.
Help = "DEMO.HLP"    ' Define Help file.
Ctxt = 1000    ' Define topic context.
        ' Display message.
Response = MsgBox(Msg, Style, Title, Help, Ctxt)
If Response = vbYes Then    ' User chose Yes.
    MyString = "Yes"    ' Perform some action.
Else    ' User chose No.
    MyString = "No"    ' Perform some action.
End If
```

Error: Invalid outside procedure

Can you help me :))?

Comment: Hi Welcome to SO.  Is it a part of a procedure ? I can see it wrapped in `Sub-End Sub` .. If it is independent procedure add `Sub Test()`  .. (or any name) at the beginning and `End Sub` at the end

Comment: I can't understand. I don't know VBA, only copy-paste. Can you send more easy comment. (I'm turkish, my english is so bad)

Comment: Add screenshot where you pasted the code... Write `Sub Test()` before the code... And ... `End Sub` after the code and then run it.

Comment: It's works. Thank you but can you send answer to answer part? cuz I mark answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write `Sub Test()` before the code... And ... `End Sub` after the code and then run it.

You can refer to [Sub statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/sub-statement)